# Socket.setTcpNoDelay() vs host setting (Nagle's Algorithm)

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, nagle

I just wanted some insight into how Nagle's algorithm is handled in regards to an application vs host.

So, say the host had TCP_NODELAY enabled, but the Java application didn't, which would take priority?

What about the other way round?

Comment: The Regustry setting determines the  default value. The Java API overrides that.

Comment: Thank you for that. Any sources on this, or just from experience? @user207421

Comment: It follows by definition, and in any case the Registry can't act dynamically on the socket after it's created. The API can.

Comment: You may be able to query to check "if it's set" using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html or possibly https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getTcpNoDelay() and come back and tell us which one takes precedence? :)

Comment: I know that it's enabled by default in the SocketOption, but I believe the specific application this is in reference to disables it, so by @user's response, I'm guessing it's disabled not matter the setting in the Windows registry. I'll look into it futher though.